# How can I make even-width columns?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am very perplexed with the XUL's 'Box Model' layout.
I want to make a table-like layout of elements.
The layout should consist of one row and three columns.
The columns should have the same width and occupy the whole width of the page.
I will put different elements inside the columns, but the width of the columns should remain the same
and the elements should have their normal sizes, not stretched out.
Say, first column is empty, second contains an image, third contains a button.
**How can I achieve that?**
I tried boxes and grids, but the columns just seem to assume arbitrary width.
Thank you.

This does not work:

```
<grid>
<columns flex="1">
  <column/>
  <column/>
  <column/>
</columns>
<rows>
  <row>
  <spacer flex="1"/>
  <image src="MyImage.png"/>
  <button id="MyButton" label="MyButton"/>
  </row>
</rows>
</grid>
```

Comment: Do you have to do XUL? Can you load a XHTML page instead? XHTML offers all the localization abilities of XUL but all the flexibility of HTML. See this as an example - github.com/Noitidart/ZooniverseXpert

Comment: With HTML its easy for people to understand, and we can use this flexible system to create even width columns - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes - but if you want to stick with XUL, the same rules apply, it just might be a bit difficult to see as by default elements are not position inline/block they are a kind of box.

Comment: Hi, Noitidart. Thanks for your help. I suppose that there are different ways to work this around, but in this particular instance I am trying to understand XUL, so the question is: is it possible to do it with XUL, or is it not possible at all?

Comment: yes its very possible. The flexible css system I think was inspired by XUL. Ill look more at your code and post a solution later, not home right now.

Comment: Thanks, will be waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the min and max width of each column and make each cell in the grid an `hbox` width specific widths and heights.  Something like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="yourwindow" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <grid>
    <columns flex="1">
        <column maxwidth="100" minwidth="100"/>
        <column maxwidth="100" minwidth="100"/>
        <column maxwidth="100" minwidth="100"/>
    </columns>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <hbox maxwidth="100">
                xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
            </hbox>
            <hbox maxwidth="100" minwidth="100" maxheight="10">
                <button id="MyButton1" label="MyButton1"/>
            </hbox>
            <hbox maxwidth="100" minwidth="100" maxheight="30">
                <button id="MyButton1" label="MyButton2"/>
            </hbox>
            <hbox maxwidth="100" minwidth="100" maxheight="40">
                <button id="MyButton3" label="MyButton3"/>
            </hbox>
        </row>
    </rows>
    </grid>
</window>
```

In Xul, the width and length attributes are always in pixels.  You cannot specify a percentage like you can with css.  This means you will have to know your page width in advance and specify widths accordingly if you want the columns to be evenly spaced and extend to the page width.

Here's another way.  Use this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="yourwindow" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" 
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <grid>
        <columns>
                <column flex="1"/>
                <column flex="1"/>
                <column flex="1"/>
        </columns>
        <rows>
            <row>          
                <button label="MyButton1"/>          
                <button label="MyButton2"/>           
                <button label="MyButton3"/>  
            </row>
        </rows>
    </grid>
</window>
```

to create this:

[image]

The buttons/columns will adjust as the window size is changed.

Comment: Hi, Chuck Baker. Thanks for your help. Unfortunately the width of the window is not known beforehand. I can adjust sizes with JavaScript, but the idea in the question was to create a layout that would adjust itself to the window's width. Like, say, three buttons with flex='1' would assume the same width and occupy all available space.

Comment: Hi, Chuck. Thanks again. This is what I was talking about how the desired effect should look like. But when I replace one button for a spacer and another button for an image, the columns do not maintain the same width anymore, despite their flex attributes being the same. Which seems opposite to what one should expect.

Comment: @GreenBear by setting flex=1 on each element, you don't need to know the width. You can copy paste this code into this live online xul tester - http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/xuledit/xuledit.xul - you need to add ted.mielczarek.org to whitelist with this addon first though - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remote-xul-manager/

Comment: Hi, Noitidart. Thanks for your suggestion with the online xul tester. I did not get which code you suggest me to check?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use in combo with flex="1" on the column elements

```
    <columns equalsize="always">
        <column flex="1">
        ...
```

a/p documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/equalsize

you can also use equalsize="always" on the rows as well, this is how it is accomplished in the Thunderbird Lightning calendar layout